# Работа на удаленном компьютере или распределение нагрузки.

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Есть планшет с док-станцией  Acer W501 на win7, домашний компьютер и MS VS. Подскажите как  наиболее выгодно (в плане быстродействия) подключаться к домашней машине удаленно, какие программы использовать и тд. А также слышал об распределении нагрузки, будто на одной машине управлялось, а на удаленной компилировалось или выполнялась другая ресурсоемкая работа. Насколько второй подход реален и какой подход эффективнее. Полезные ссылки приветствуются. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SSH - быстро и безопасно](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH)

По сути это удаленное управление командной строкой, без загрузки каких либо графических окон.

SSH-клиенты и оболочки:

```
MS Windows и Windows NT: PuTTY, SecureCRT, ShellGuard, Axessh, ZOC, SSHWindows, ProSSHD, XShell
```

Comment: Сдается мне, что с планшета это будет не самое удобное времяпрепровождение :)

Comment: Котик_хочет_кушать, он как нетбук, по пилить небольшие модули можно, но не больше))